Issues with realtek drivers for my Wifi Network USB Adapter
So my wifi network adapter is not recognizable by ubuntu server. I've tried the https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu driver but looks like it doesn't work on my platform. It's aarch64 OrangePi 3B. Is there any chance I can make it to work on the platform? Thanks for any answers!
